# Chrome MediaSession API Without Audio

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, media-player, html5-audio

I'm developing a web application that let's users on the local network control a media server.

I want Android users to see the media notification from Chrome, is there a way to use the Media Session API without having an actual `<audio>` tag?
Or should I put an empty audio tag on the page and spoof it that way.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session

Edit: I answered my own question by reading a different document:

> Note that:  Notifications are only shown for media over five seconds
>   in length. There is no notification for audio from the Web Audio API
>   unless it is played back via an audio element. With the Media Session
>   API, you can customize media notifications by providing metadata for
>   the media your web app is playing. This API also allows you to handle
>   media related events such as seeking or track changing which may come
>   from notifications or media keys.

From: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/media-notifications

I was able to use https://github.com/anars/blank-audio to trigger the notification and then set the meta data to what was actually playing.

```
setUpNotification = () => {
    if (!this.audioTag) {
      this.audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
      document.body.appendChild(this.audioTag);
      this.audioTag.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anars/blank-audio/master/10-seconds-of-silence.mp3";
      this.audioTag.loop = true;
      this.audioTag.play();
    }
  }

richMediaNotification = () => {
    if (this.audioTag) {

      let { playing } = this.state;
      let song = this.state.Queue.CurrentSong;

      navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
        title: song.Name,
        artist: song.Artist,
        album: song.Album,
        artwork: [{ src: song.Image }]
      });

      navigator.mediaSession.playbackState = playing ? "playing" : "paused"

      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => this.state.socket.emit("prevTrack"));
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => this.state.socket.emit("nextTrack"));
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => { this.audioTag.play(); this.state.socket.emit("playpause") });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => { this.audioTag.pause(); this.state.socket.emit("playpause") });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Evan, welcome to SO! Everyone has at some point has asked a similar question, but I'd avoid asking a "I want to do this, help me" questions before actually trying to do it yourself. If you have, could you post some code so people can understand the query better and get some context? Thanks!

Comment: @Mese Thanks for the comment! This was just one of those things that I could only find the official documentation for and no threads about. I wanted to get a feel for if people had tried this before or not. I was away from any workstation for a little and was just excited about the thought of it haha.

Comment: @EvanBurgess Rather than editing your question, you can post your own answer, it will bring more visibility to your solution (and more upvotes!)

Comment: Thanks mate.  Works a treat! Well at least on the desktop that is... doesn't seem to work on mobile chrome....